# How to use the Titan Extractor?

Tags: warframe

On Warframe, they recently added a new item called the Titan Extractor. After building it, I have no I idea what I need to do with it. It says it goes to planets to collect resources, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've built the extractor (the blueprint is reusable), you can deploy it to any planet you've fully unlocked (just *unlocking* all missions there is enough, no need to *beat* everything). There will be a button labelled "Deploy Extractor" on the left side of the mission select screen for that planet. Press that, then select which extractor you want to put to work (if you have more than one).

Once the extractor is deployed, a 4-hour timer will start. You can return the extractor at any time, but that won't give you any resources, but incur no penalty of any kind. Once the 4 hours are out, that same button will change to "Claim", which will give you the resources collected and start the extractor again on the same planet.

The little red bar under the extractor's icon shows its remaining integrity. Once that drops to 0, the extractor is destroyed, no resources can be claimed from it, and it can't be reused. You'll have to build a new one. Damage seems to occur randomly while it's deployed.

Leaving an extractor in your inventory and not in use replenishes its health over time automatically.

Comment: Your last statement is not true, they have changed it so you can have more than one extractor now, I think it is tied to mastery rank.

Comment: Oh, really? I'll check it out next time I play. Thanks!

Comment: Ya, the amount of extractors is linked to your Mastery Rank .

Answer (score 1):

To deploy it you have to go to the mission selection of the planet you want to deploy it to and you should see a deploy button over the box that indicates what resources you can get from the planet.

[image: Deploy Extractor on star map]

[According to the Warframe wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Titan_Extractor) this can only be done on plants where you have accesse to all missions.

The amount you can deoloys is as following([source](https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/150623-update-1150-the-cicero-crisis/)):

> You get one for every five mastery ranks.
>
> - Mastery 0 – 4, 1 drone
> - Master 5- 9, 2 drones
> - Master 10 +,  3 drones.
> - All Founders/Primes Access get +1 to each tier.
>
> So if you are Mastery 14 and Founder, you get 4. If Mastery 14 and no
>   Founder status, you get 3.